# Fitting variable images into RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, xml, image, layout, android-recyclerview

I have multiple images of different dimensions that I'm trying to display one after another in a RecyclerView, but I want each image to take up the entirety of each card in the RecyclerView, such that the card stretches the entirety of the width of the screen but can have variable length (to maintain aspect ratio). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: maybe try setting width of imageview to match_parent and scale_type to center_crop?